# Cannot open a local file using fopen()

Tags: php, xml, fopen, xlink

HI. i am trying to open a local file from xml created by xlink i have parsed the file path in $resourceRef variable and it looks like that `file:/./birds/birds.txt` without the quotes. Please someone tell me why i cant open it. here is my code

```
$fh = fopen($resourceRef, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($resourceRef));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

i get this error

> Warning: fopen(file:/./birds/feathers.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 31

Please someone guide me.

Comment: `file:/./birds/birds.txt` is not a valid URI.

Comment: can you paste the XML that you are getting this URI from?  Are you prepending file:/ to the URL?  And forgive my ignorance, but I thought xlink was a spec - is it also a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI doesn't look correct, it should be either `file://birds/birds.txt` or just `birds/birds.txt`.

Comment: file:/./birds/birds.txt is in the xml file and its done by using xlink. how can i change it..there are or will be a lot...please advise me is there a way i can do it.

Comment: How about a simple str_replace('file:/', 'file://'); ?

Answer (score 0):

Argument should be suitable path for a given platform (For widows "C:\\dir(...)" ), or correct URI ( file:// (...) )

Comment: file:/./birds/birds.txt is in the xml file and its done by using xlink. how can i change it..there are or will be a lot

Comment: use string replace function to replace "file:/./" to "file://./" this will correct string to valid URI, but still You have to deal with relative paths, (that dot in path) for this to work, php script should be in same directory as xlink generated file

Comment: what about if i take away file:/./ from file:/./birds/birds.txt so it will be birds/birds.txt and it works . i think this should be better. all the links and pictures, txt files are in a seperate folder.

do u think i can do it by using string replace or some other function.

Comment: You have to convert string, to a valid path or a valid URI, in any other case, fopen will fail to open file, You can use regular expressions, string replace function and any other bunch of available stuff to make this a valid information, about where file lays :)

Comment: and PHP gives You functions such as file_exists($file) to test/help if You have changed file path/URI correctly.

For example: remove (replace file:/./ to empty string), and perpend a valid path for directory where You have that files, to file name, if done right, should work